# How to calculate T-test from two Pandas data frame row-by-row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have the following two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
               's1': [10,10,12,13,14,15],
               's2': [100,100,112,1.3,14,125],
               's2': [13,200,10,13,14.5,10.5],
               'gene_symbol': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
               })

df_b = pd.DataFrame({
               's1': [15,20,123,13,14,15,1],
               's2': [130,100,72,1.3,14,125,2],
               's2': [213,200,35.4,13,414.5,130.5,3],
               'gene_symbol': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g'],
               })

df_a.set_index('gene_symbol', inplace=True)
df_b.set_index('gene_symbol', inplace=True)
```

Which looks like this:

```
             s1     s2
gene_symbol
a            10   13.0
b            10  200.0
c            12   10.0
d            13   13.0
e            14   14.5
f            15   10.5

In [51]: df_b
Out[51]:
              s1     s2
gene_symbol
a             15  213.0
b             20  200.0
c            123   35.4
d             13   13.0
e             14  414.5
f             15  130.5
g              1    3.0
```

What I want to do is to calculate T-test p-value gene by gene.
For example for gene `a` we will have

```
In [47]: scipy.stats.ttest_ind([ 10,13.0],[15,213.0])
Out[47]: Ttest_indResult(statistic=-1.0352347135782713, pvalue=0.4093249100598676)
```

How can I apply that for all rows that shares common genes for two data frames (e.g. ignore gene `g` in `df_b`).

I tried this but it failed:

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df_a, df_b,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `g` row using your `gene_symbol` index by matching two dataframes, or indexes.

You can use [pandas.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to join two DataFrames on matching columns or indexes, and use the columns of the merged DataFrame on ttest_ind:

```
# default join is inner
df_m = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df_m.ix[:, :2], df_m.ix[:, 2:], axis=1)
```

Or you can find the [intersection](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) of the indexes and use them to slice your datasets:

```
idx = df_a.index.intersection(df_b.index)
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df_a.loc[idx], df_b.loc[idx], axis=1)
```

Comment: I find the walk-throughs on Greg Reda's post "[Working with Dataframes](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/#Joining)" to be very helpful. Especially the section on joining.