# python group by based on column headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have csv file with 744 rows and 186 columns with the following format:

```
 Label   1          1         0         0         1
 TaxID   P_ERR161   P_ERR162  P_ERR163  P_ERR164  P_ERR165 
 333046  0.05       0         22.33     0.06      7.32
 1049    0.03       0         0.04      0.01      0.02
 337090  0.01       0         9.79      45.88     3.99   
 288681  3.6        0         1.03      251.01    8.11
```

I need to group the row values based on the label 0 and 1 into two separate dataframes. I have seen other posts but unable to find the solution to my problem. I need this for statistical analysis like t test, wilcoxon rank sum test.

I have tried this :

```
df = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')
case = df.where(df.Label == 1).dropna()['SRA ID']
ctrl = df.where(df.Label == 2).dropna()['SRA ID']
```

But this isn't helping me. Any help will be really useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Specifically, it would be extremely helpful if you can print `df.head(5)`. This way we can easily test code which we provide as an answer.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis sure i will edit the question.

Comment: so you want 2 dataframes, one with just 0 cols and one with just 1 columns, is that right? This is usually called "slicing", not "grouping" - which is reserved for when we aggregate data according to fields / criteria.

Comment: I think what you need is a MultiIndex: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis yes two different dataframes one with the column headers 0 and other with column headers 1. Sorry I am new to python hence not very good it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need parameter `header` for `Multiindex` from second and third row in `csv` and then seelct by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df  = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0])
#print (df.head())


case = df.xs('0', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
#print (case.head())

ctrl = df.xs('1', axis=1, level=0).dropna()
#print (ctrl.head())
```

Comment: @jezreal how am I suppoese to take 186 rows for : `MultiIndex(levels=[['0', '1'], ['P_ERR161', 'P_ERR162', 'P_ERR163', 'P_ERR164', 'P_ERR165']]        labels=[[1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], `

Comment: Are your data confidental?

Comment: @jezreal no it not

Comment: OK, maybe some problem with data. Can you send me your csv to my email in my profile? I test it with your real data.

Comment: Sure i will e mail you

Comment: Done.  Kindly check

Comment: I have one question. In data are first 3 rows header. Second row is 0 and 1 for splitting, but first and third row are necessary? Is possible remove first or third or remove both. What do you think?

Comment: First row can be removed. Second row is important as in contains Labels and third row are the project ID. So

Comment: Thanks it worked. But after using the`case` and `control` in `(tt_val, p_ttest) = ttest_ind(case, ctrl)` I am getting the error                                                      `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (92,) (95,)`. Any help with this ?

Comment: Yes, it means first dataframe has 62 columns and second 95. I guess need same number.

Comment: i cannot have same number that how the data is suppose to be. Is there any other way to handle this error ?

Comment: First I am not statistician, so hard answer. I do some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107218/2901002) and it seems need intersection of columns names in both DataFrames. But there are no common names. One possible solution is get minimal columns lengths and filter by it. `lens = min(len(case.columns), len(ctrl.columns))`,  `print (scipy.stats.ttest_ind(case.iloc[:, :lens], ctrl.iloc[:, :lens], axis=1))`. But please consult this solution wby some statistician if it is correct way for this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :) I will check this how it works for me

Comment: Hi, actually the problem was objects created by the `xs` method of the Pandas DataFrame look like two-dimensional arrays. These must be flattened to look like one-dimensional arrays when passed to `ttest_ind`. The `values` attribute of the Pandas objects gives a numpy array, and the `ravel()` method flattens the array to one-dimension.

Comment: Hmmm, if need id array use `case.iloc[:, :lens].values.ravel()` only.

Comment: But I will require your help for one more thing. how can I iterate it through rows So that it will take value of only one row for `label 0 and 1` for ttest.

Comment: but I dont know if it is what you need.

Comment: for loop you need [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Comment: Actually I need the result of ttest row wise for which i guess i need to iterate. as on now im getting only one value.

Comment: I did that but im getting same value for all the rows.

Comment: OK, so if `df  = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0]).iloc[:5, :10]` DataFrame, what is expected output?

Comment: The expected out will be for each row the `label values 0 and 1` should be in `case` and `ctrl` and then I will apply the formula for ttest that would be `(tt_val,p_ttest ) = ttest_ind(case.values.ravel(), ctrl.values.ravel(), equal_var=False)`.

Comment: What is expected output for first 2 rows of `df = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0]).iloc[:5, :10]` ? Some list? Array? What are values from data?

Comment: It should be array. values like this `tt_ val = 0.524313022766` and `p_val = 0.600061676721` for each row. Now Im getting these same values for every row.

Comment: OK, please give me values.

Comment: This are the values you are looking for ?

Comment: Ok, so for first row in `df = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0]).iloc[:5, :10]` are `tt_ val = 0.524313022766 and p_val = 0.600061676721` ? What is second row?

Comment: For second row also Im getting the  value `tt_val = 0.452012246367` and `p_val = 0.652790084075`

Comment: How do you count it? I get different numebrs.

Comment: I use `df = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv', header=[1,2], index_col=[0]).iloc[:5, :10]`, then `case = df.xs('0', axis=1, level=0)` and `ctrl = df.xs('1', axis=1, level=0)`

Comment: Then test first row by `print (scipy.stats.ttest_ind(case.iloc[0].values.ravel(), ctrl.iloc[0].values.ravel(), equal_var=False))` and it is same as `print (scipy.stats.ttest_ind(case, ctrl, equal_var=False, axis=1))` for all rows (check first values)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164342/discussion-between-k-s-and-jezrael).